# Ruby on rails devkit windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, devkit

I am having a problem in installing devkit of ruby on rails. Here's the error I got

```
C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb review
Based upon the settings in the 'config.yml' file generated
from running 'ruby dk.rb init' and any of your customizations,
DevKit functionality will be injected into the following Rubies
when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:/Ruby192
C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1

C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby192'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
[ERROR] Unable to find RubyGems in site_ruby or core Ruby. Please install RubyGems and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'.
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Ruby Gems installed?

Comment: You should have - if you used the RubyInstaller.

Comment: @Brian - Yes I have ruby gem installed

Comment: @Stephen Orr - Yes I installed that, I am using Aptana Studio 3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error is that you added `C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1` to the list of Ruby installations.

By default `dk.rb` will not find that and actually that is not a valid path.

Please ensure `config.yml` contains just this:

```
- C:/Ruby192
```

The dash is important

Once you do that, try `ruby dk.rb install` again.

Comment: Hi, it works now however I encountered a Warning C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby192'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby192'

Comment: The warning is because you installed it the first time :-P entering `ruby dk.rb` will provide you a list of options, including a way to force the installation of the devkit if one was already installed (like your case). As the notice say, it was a warning that it skipped.

Comment: The dash! I nearly went into the registries but this has fixed the issue of not picking up existing ruby installations.

Answer (score 2):

Open `config.yml` and configure the diretory of Ruby EX: `C:/Ruby192`